# Counting names in Coldfusion

Tags: list, coldfusion, counting

I have a List :

- Mike
- Peter
- Marshall
- Mike
- Peter
- Mike
- Peter
- Marie
- John
- Peter
- Marshall
- Mike
- Steven

And I want to count how often one of the Names appeard in that list.

Like:

- Mike = 4
- Peter = 4
- Marshall = 2
- Marie = 1
- John = 1
- Steven = 1

How can I do that (btw Im really new so this is a beginner question)

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion? And in what form does this list present itself to you in? IE: what code have you got that ends with a variable of some description containing all those names? And what have you tried? Post all relevant code (but only enough to demonstrate the current state of your investigation, without other unnecessary stuff). Read this: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 9):

You can `loop` over the `list` and can create a structure using `names as key` and their `count as values` like this:

```
<cfset names = "Mike,Peter,Marshall,Mike,Peter,Mike,Peter,Marie,John,Peter,Marshall,Mike,Steven">
<cfset nameCount = structNew()>
<cfloop list="#names#" index="currentName" delimiters=",">
  <cfif structKeyExists(nameCount, currentName)>
    <cfset nameCount[currentName] += 1>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset nameCount[currentName] = 1>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but note that if this is data in a database then it can be done much more efficiently in SQL. This answer, however, is correct for the question as it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Beginner gives you a struct that contains the number of occurrences for every item of the list.

If you want to know how often an arbitrary string occurs in this list, you can use the build in functions `listValueCount(list, value)` and  `listValueCountNoCase(list, value)`.

```
<cfset names = "Mike,Peter,Marshall,Mike,Peter,Mike,Peter,Marie">
<!--- x = 3 --->
<cfset x = listValueCount(names, "Mike")>
<!--- x = 0 --->
<cfset x = listValueCount(names, "Steve")>
```